# Lua mount filesystem

Tags: lua, filesystems, mount

I want to mount a filesystem on Linux using Lua, but I haven't found any capability in the [lua 5.4 manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html) or the [LuaFileSytem](https://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem/manual.html) library. Is there some way to mount a filesystem in Lua or with an existing library?

Comment: `pipe('mount ...')` or `FFI.C.mount(...)` ? For the latter, I do not remember the exact syntax.

Comment: You'll need a way to request user password, possibly with fltk4lua, then `os .execute( 'echo ' ..password ..' | sudo -S ' ..command )`

Comment: I'm actually not worried about a password, and I don't want to use pipe or execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most platform-dependent syscall, Lua won't provide such mapping out of the box.
So you'll need some C-API module that does the trick.
Looks like https://github.com/justincormack/ljsyscall is generic "but" focused on LuaJIT and https://luaposix.github.io/luaposix/ doesn't provide `mount`.

I recently had similar needs, and I ended doing the C module:

```
static int l_mount(lua_State* L)
{
    int res = 0;
    // TODO add more checks on args!
    const char *source = luaL_checkstring(L, 1);
    const char *target = luaL_checkstring(L, 2);
    const char *type   = luaL_checkstring(L, 3);
    lua_Integer flags  = luaL_checkinteger(L, 4);
    const char *data   = luaL_checkstring(L, 5);

    res = mount(source, target, type, flags, data);
    if ( res != 0)
    {
        int err = errno;
        lua_pushnil(L);
        lua_pushfstring(L, "mount failed: errno[%s]", strerror(err));
        return 2;
    }
    else
    {
        lua_pushfstring(L, "ok");
        return 1;
    }
}

#define register_constant(s)\
    lua_pushinteger(L, s);\
    lua_setfield(L, -2, #s);

// Module functions
static const luaL_Reg R[] =
{
    { "mount", l_mount },
    { NULL, NULL }
};

int luaopen_sysutils(lua_State* L)
{
    luaL_newlib(L, R);

    // do more mount defines mapping, maybe in some table.
    register_constant(MS_RDONLY);
    //...
    
    return 1;
}
```

Compile this as a C Lua module, and don't forget that you need  `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` to call `mount` syscall.